# Why do I get the same value with 2 different "instances"

Tags: javascript, signalr

I know javascript "classes" aren't like most languages exactly, but I'm trying to figure out why my callback from SignalR is printing out 20 for both instances when I set 2 different values in their constructors.

```
class gameLoad{
            constructor(value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            init(){
                // create the network object and hook it's functions update
                this.network = $.connection.testHub;
                this.network.client.hello = this.sayHello.bind(this);

                console.log(this.value);
            }

            // this is called from signalR and 'this' now refers to the signalR hub inside this function. how can I get the class instance?
            sayHello(){
                console.log(this.value);        //<--- this prints 20 2 times
            }

            create(){
                var self = this;

                // start the hub connection
                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    console.log("Started!")
                    console.log("Calling server function.");

                    // make our first network call which will turn around and fire client.hello which is bound to this classes sayHello()
                    self.network.server.hello();
                });
            }
        }

        var game1 = new gameLoad(10);

        game1.init();
        game1.create();

        var game2 = new gameLoad(20);

        game2.init();
        game2.create();
```

Comment: 20 is printed 2 times because it is printed once in the constructor and the second time is when init() is called

Comment: Sorry, I mean it prints twice at the end. I get 10 printed twice then 20 printed twice, then "Started! Calling server function" printed twice, then 20 printed twice. It's coming back from the SignalR call and SignalR is calling hello which is bound to sayHello.

Comment: The server HUB function and the client function are just named the same.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what's happening. The 2nd binding to client.hello is the one that takes. The call to the server takes longer since it's async so when it's ready to come back to the client and raise the javascript function the binding that exists is the 20 instance one. Since it's not adding multiple hooks just 1. hmm, wonder if I can get multiple hooks for callbacks.